# Europa Universalis IV won't work because of (0xc000007b)

Tags: technical-issues, europa-universalis-iv

Every time I try to run the game, it runs into an error in the application (0xc000007b). Why does this happens?
I've tried everything on YouTube, but nothing works.

Comment: What's the "everything in YouTube" you've tried? Why did you add tags for Crusader Kings 2 and 3 and Stellaris? Also: what Windows version are you using (if at all)?

Comment: @Joachim i had the same problem with them all but all worked except EU4 , this was trying to replace dlls and add dlls  , also to reinstall with antivirus turned off but nothing worked

Comment: And how did you fix the problem with the other games? I wouldn't go around removing, downloading and (re)placing .dlls at random, though, as that might cause more problems.

Comment: @Joachim i did what you wouldnt fo around for , replacing dlls .

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can try:

- Update your GPU drivers ([Nvidia](https://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/index.aspx) / [Radeon](https://www.amd.com/en/support)).
- [Run the game in Administrator mode](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/2906376154316676882/).
- (Re)installing the [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170).
- (Re)install [DirectX](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35).
- And, as a user on the Paradox forums [mentions](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/threads/0xc00007b-error.1248151/post-25835287):

  > Also try this, please: **Add EU4.exe to the exceptions list of your antivirus app**; ESPECIALLY if you have Windows Defender, add it to the Ransomware "*Apps allowed through list.*"
- Check if you have any pending Windows updates, and install them.
- Run [SFC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e).
- Run [DISM](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image) (on Windows 10).

If you want to keep trying replacing or deleting .dll files, you'd better use an app like [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/), as it lets you know what processes might actually be missing.